# Getting a ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND error in javascript

Tags: javascript

So i am trying to make a guess the number game in javascript it is a beginner project but i don't know whats going wrong with the code. Any experienced javascript coder can help me figure this out?
Here's my code:

```
import * as random from 'random';
import * as colorama from 'colorama';
import { Fore } from 'colorama';
var SecretNumber, chances, guess;
SecretNumber = random.randrange({
  "start": 1,
  "stop": 35
});
console.log(Fore.MAGENTA + "Guess the randomly generated number from 1 to 35");
chances = 1;
guess = null;

while (guess !== SecretNumber) {
  guess = Number.parseInt(input("Guess a number between 1 and 35: "));

  if (guess > SecretNumber) {
    console.log(Fore.RED + "Guess Lower!");
    chances += 1;

    if (guess > 35) {
      console.log("Sorry that's above the limit");
    }
  } else {
    if (guess < SecretNumber) {
      console.log(Fore.GREEN + "Guess Higher!");
      chances += 1;
    } else {
      if (guess === SecretNumber) {
        console.log(Fore.YELLOW + "Hurray! You got it in {} tries, the number was {}".format(chances, SecretNumber));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting an error  that says:

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '/Users/username/Desktop/Python/node_modules/colorama/' imported from /Users/username/Desktop/Python/script.js
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
at legacyMainResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:341:9)
at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:941:14)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1003:20)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1218:11)
at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:580:30)
at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:294:18)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:80:40)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing colorama through npm.

```
npm i colorama
```

And try again.

Comment: no not working.

Comment: @ArnavChetanYadwadkar still the _exact_ same error, or is it now complaining about `random`? Because you can probably guess how _that_ should be solved.

Comment: exact same error.

Comment: Try this and tell me if works: https://blog.finxter.com/fixed-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-colorama/

Comment: no that is also not working

Comment: NOW IT IS COMPLAINING ABOUT THE RANDOM MODULE

Comment: @robertklep it is complaining about the random module